# Select only visible text fields in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a nicer way in jQuery to do this ?

```
$(":text").each(function() {
   if (this.style.visibility == "visible") {
      ...
   };
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes:

```
$(":text:visible").each(function() {
   ...
});
```

**UPDATE** Since jQuery this doesn't work anymore: [details](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3.2#:visible.2F:hidden_Overhauled).

Comment: Note that this is probably what the OP wants, but not the literal translation (since they're using `visibility` and not `display`).

Comment: @Nick, in that case, `$(":text:visible, :text:not(':hidden')".each(..` would work.

Comment: None of the options above works for me :( Note that I set the "visibility" like this: $("#myid").attr("style", "visibility: hidden");    What I see is all elements including the hidden ones...

Comment: For setting visibility you should use: $("#myid").css("visibility","hidden"). Also note the updated answer..

Comment: What is the difference between $("#myid").attr("style", "visibility: hidden") and $("#myid").css("visibility","hidden") ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector:

```
$(':text:visible')
```

Answer (score 0):

For speed use

```
$(':text').filter(":visible")
```